What is the best strategy for autogenerating primary key fields in Hilla.Dev on Cassandra?
I am working on the Hilla.dev stack which is basically a bridge between Spring Boot and React (with typescript). But I am having problems with data type conversion of primary keys between java and typescript.
Hilla.dev fails to convert the UUID datatype to a typescript type. The Long datatype does work, but you have to manually implement autogeneration of ids.
Java model:
        package com.example.application.model;
        import lombok.Builder;
        import lombok.Data;
        import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
        import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
        import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
        
        import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
        import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
        import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;
        
        import java.io.Serializable;
        
        import java.time.LocalDate;
        import java.util.UUID;
        
        
        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor 
        //@Builder
        @Table("materia")
        
        public class Materia implements Serializable {
        
            @PrimaryKey
            private Long id;
        
        
            @Column("nombre")
            private String nombre;
        
            @Column("descripcion")
            private String descripcion;
        
        }

Service:
      package com.example.application.services;
        
        
        import com.example.application.model.Materia;
        import com.example.application.repository.MateriaRepository;
        
        import com.example.application.services.MateriaService.MateriaRecord;
        import com.vaadin.flow.server.auth.AnonymousAllowed;
        
        import dev.hilla.BrowserCallable;
        import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
        
        import java.time.LocalDate;
        import java.util.HashSet;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Optional;
        import java.util.Set;
        import java.util.UUID;
        import java.util.stream.Stream;
        
        import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
        import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
        
        @Service
        @AnonymousAllowed
        @BrowserCallable
        public class MateriaService {
        
            private final MateriaRepository repository;
        
            public record MateriaRecord(
                    Long id,
                    // nombre de la aplicación
                    @NotNull             
                    String nombre,            
                    
                    @NotNull             
                    String descripcion
        
                    ) {
            }
        
            public MateriaService(MateriaRepository repository) {
                this.repository = repository;
            }
        
            private MateriaRecord toMateriaRecord(Materia laMateria) {
                return new MateriaRecord(
                        laMateria.getId(),
                        laMateria.getNombre(), 
                        laMateria.getDescripcion() 
        
                        );
            }
        
            public MateriaRecord saveMateria(MateriaRecord nuevaMateria) {
                // Crea un nuevo objeto Materia y asigna los valores del objeto recibido
                Materia dbMateria = new Materia();
                dbMateria.setId((long) 4234234); 
                dbMateria.setNombre(nuevaMateria.nombre);        
                dbMateria.setDescripcion(nuevaMateria.descripcion);        
                //dbMateria.setDesde(nuevaMateria.desde);        
                //dbMateria.setHasta(nuevaMateria.hasta);
                // Guarda el nuevo organismo en la base de datos
                System.out.println("ID "+dbMateria.getId());
                Materia savedMateria = repository.save(dbMateria);
        
                // Devuelve el organismo guardado después de convertirlo a MateriaRecord 
                return toMateriaRecord(savedMateria);
            }
        
            private MateriaRecord updateMateria(MateriaRecord laMateria) {
                var dbMateria = repository.findById(laMateria.id).orElseThrow();
        
                dbMateria.setNombre(laMateria.nombre);        
               // dbMateria.setDesde(laMateria.desde);        
               // dbMateria.setHasta(laMateria.hasta);        
                dbMateria.setNombre(laMateria.descripcion);        
        
                Materia savedMateria = repository.save(dbMateria);
                
                return toMateriaRecord(savedMateria);
            }
        
            public void delete(Long id) {
                repository.deleteById(id);
            }
            
            public List<MateriaRecord> findAllMaterias() {
                Stream<Materia> listaResul = repository.findAll().stream();
                
                return listaResul.map(this::toMateriaRecord).toList();
            }
        
            public MateriaRecord save(MateriaRecord laMateria) {
               
                MateriaRecord rta;
                // var dbMateria = repository.findById(elMateria.id);
                if (laMateria.id() == 0)   {         
                    System.out.println("oneeeeeeeeee");
                    rta = this.saveMateria(laMateria);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("twooooooooooo");
                    rta = this.updateMateria(laMateria);            
                }    
                return rta;
            }
        
        
        }

Self generated record by Hilla
      import { _getPropertyModel as _getPropertyModel_1, makeObjectEmptyValueCreator as makeObjectEmptyValueCreator_1, NotNull as NotNull_1, NumberModel as NumberModel_1, ObjectModel as ObjectModel_1, StringModel as StringModel_1 } from "@hilla/form";
        import type MateriaRecord_1 from "./MateriaRecord.js";
        class MateriaRecordModel<T extends MateriaRecord_1 = MateriaRecord_1> extends ObjectModel_1<T> {
            static override createEmptyValue = makeObjectEmptyValueCreator_1(MateriaRecordModel);
            get id(): NumberModel_1 {
                return this[_getPropertyModel_1]("id", (parent, key) => new NumberModel_1(parent, key, false, { meta: { javaType: "java.lang.Long" } }));
            }
            get nombre(): StringModel_1 {
                return this[_getPropertyModel_1]("nombre", (parent, key) => new StringModel_1(parent, key, false, { validators: [new NotNull_1()], meta: { javaType: "java.lang.String" } }));
            }
            get descripcion(): StringModel_1 {
                return this[_getPropertyModel_1]("descripcion", (parent, key) => new StringModel_1(parent, key, false, { validators: [new NotNull_1()], meta: { javaType: "java.lang.String" } }));
            }
        }
        export default MateriaRecordModel;


The code example doesn't seem to be using the UUID import for anything, only Long. How are you converting from UUID to long?
